# Best way to search attributes table in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search

I have 2 tables

```
header 
(
    id uniqueidentifier,
    code varchar(25),
    description varchar(150),
    ...
)

attributes
(
    headerId uniqueidentifier,
    attributeId uniqueidentifier,
    stringColumn varchar(100),
    integerColumn int,
    decimalColumn decimal(16,5),
    booleanColumn bit,
    textColumn varchar(500),
    ...
)
```

Baisically I would like to implement a general search that would find the `header.Id` of all the headers that have related attributes with a value of some search string.

I know that a search index would be ideal for that. But currently not planed to implement that.

My current plan is to make an `attributeMeta varchar(max)` column in the header table and store a json inside the column containing all the attribute data and then do a fullText search index on it and query it.

Would that be fine or is there a better solution? given that I should not implement a search index as of now?

Comment: Your code looks somewhere in-between a  class and a table... Is there only only the 1 varchar column? Size of that column?

Comment: there are 2 varchar columns one for short strings and one for long

Comment: Just do a full text search on those 2 columns, no need for another column with repetitive data

Answer (score 0):

if youre using sql server, try :::

```
ALTER TABLE header
ADD COLUMN attributeMeta VARCHAR(MAX)

UPDATE TABLE header
SET attributeMeta =
SELECT
headerId +','+
attributeId +','+
stringColumn +','+
integerColumn +','+
decimalColumn +','+
booleanColumn        -- CONCAT AS MANY TABLES AS YOU NEED
FROM attributes
WHERE id = attributes .headerId)    --im assuming attributes.headerId and headers.id can be used to link the tables
```

but my best bet would be to create index in the appropriate fields and tables.